# Drag and move HTML elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, desktop, drag

I have a web page where various amounts of HTML elements (Div's all with the class Character) are generated depending on a sperate PHP Script pulling from an SQL backend.

Once The elements are created this script should make them able to click and drag the elements around the screen. The code works for mobile but doesn't for Desktop. The result is that the elements snap move after the first click whenever the cursor touches them and it seems as tho the mouseup event is never called.

I've tried many variations and below is my latest attempt.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.Character');

// Loop through the list of elements
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  // Get the current element
  var Character = elements[i];

  //moblie touch events 
  Character.addEventListener("touchmove", dragTouch);

  //desktop click events
  Character.addEventListener("mousedown", dragMouseDown);
}

var pos1 = 0,
  pos2 = 0,
  pos3 = 0,
  pos4 = 0;

function dragTouch(e) {
  var touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
  //set Location to centre of charcter icon
  var offsetX = this.offsetWidth / 2;
  var offsetY = this.offsetHeight / 2;

  //Move character
  this.style.left = (touchLocation.clientX - offsetX) + "px";
  this.style.top = (touchLocation.clientY - offsetY) + "px";
}

var initialX = 0;
var initialY = 0;

function dragMouseDown(e) {
  // Save the initial position of the mouse cursor
  initialX = e.pageX;
  initialY = e.pageY;
  // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
  this.addEventListener("mousemove", elementDrag.bind(this));
  this.addEventListener("mouseup", dragMouseUp);
}

// Use the initial position of the mouse cursor to calculate the element's new position
function elementDrag(e) {
  var currentX = e.pageX;
  var currentY = e.pageY;
  this.style.top = this.offsetTop + (currentY - initialY) + "px";
  this.style.left = this.offsetLeft + (currentX - initialX) + "px";
}

function dragMouseUp() {
  // stop moving when mouse button is released:
  this.removeEventListener("mousemove", elementDrag);
}
```

```css
.Character {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #50a581;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

#mapContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(./../images/maps/dragons_rest_Dragons_rest.jpeg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  height: 90vh;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <link href='./../fontawesome/css/all.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
        <link href='./../css/myStyle.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />      
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="nav-placeholder"></div>
        </header>
        <div id="mapContainer">
            <?php
            // Connect to the database
            $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'webserver', '654321', 'webserver');

            // Query the database for the data you want to display
            $result = $db->query('SELECT charID, name, color FROM charTable');

            // Check if there are any results
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // Loop through the results
                $list = array();
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $list[] = array (
                    'charID' => $row['charID'],
                    'charName' => $row['name'],
                    'charColor' => $row['color'],
                );
                }
                foreach ($list as $item){
                    $charID = $item['charID'];
                    $charName = $item['charName'];
                    $charColor = $item['charColor'];
                    $style = "style='background-color:".$charColor.";'";
                    $html = "<div class='Character'draggable='true' $style>$charName</div>";
                    echo $html;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){
        $("#nav-placeholder").load("navbarNew.html");
        });
        </script>
        <script src="./../js/movementV3.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added a snippet - please add HTML, CSS and frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using the [dragend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragend_event) event?

```js
document.addEventListener( "dragover", e => e.preventDefault() );

const chars = document.querySelectorAll(".Character");

for ( let i = 0, len = chars.length; i < len; i++ ){
  const rect = chars[i].getBoundingClientRect();
  chars[i].addEventListener( "dragend", e => end.call( chars[i], e, [rect.left, rect.top]) );
  chars[i].addEventListener("touchmove", e => dragTouch.call( chars[i], e) );
}
function end(e, [left,top]){
  this.style.left = (e.clientX - left - (this.offsetWidth/2)) + "px";
  this.style.top  = (e.clientY - top - (this.offsetHeight/2)) + "px";
}
function dragTouch(e) {
  let touchLocation = e.targetTouches[0];
  let offsetX = this.offsetWidth / 2;
  let offsetY = this.offsetHeight / 2;
  this.style.left = (touchLocation.clientX - offsetX) + "px";
  this.style.top = (touchLocation.clientY - offsetY) + "px";
}
```

```html
<style>
  .Character {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>
<button class="Character" draggable="true">Drag Me #1</button>
<button class="Character" draggable="true">Drag Me #2</button>
<button class="Character" draggable="true">Drag Me #3</button>
```

Comment: That Is a much better way of doing that. Tho only worked for desktop. I added the below line to your for loop and the orginal touch function which resolves that. chars[i].addEventListener("touchmove", e => dragTouch.call( chars[i], e) );

Comment: Other than an Offset Issue which i should be able to resolve thats worked really well Thank you!

Comment: worked well with GitHub desktop popups, thanks